# Can't get Formview to update, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, formview

I'm messing around with a Formview in asp.net. I know that the UpdateCommand needs to be specified so that the Formview knows what SQL query to run.

Do I need to write an event **in addition** to the code the Formview sets up in order to properly fire off the SQL query?

In addition, I don't get a SQL error or anything, it just does not bind back to the database.

```
<EditItemTemplate>
        ProductID:
        <asp:Label ID="ProductIDLabel1" runat="server" 
            Text='<%# Eval("ProductID") %>' />
        <br />
        ProductName:
        <asp:TextBox ID="ProductNameTextBox" runat="server" 
            Text='<%# Bind("ProductName") %>' />
        <br />
        UnitPrice:
        <asp:TextBox ID="UnitPriceTextBox" runat="server" 
            Text='<%# Bind("UnitPrice") %>' />
        <br />
        <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" 
            CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
        &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateCancelButton" runat="server" 
            CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
    </EditItemTemplate>
```

Comment: is your formview in updatepanel?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set the DataKeys property (usually to the column(s) that are your primary key). If you want more help, you'll need to post your code.

Comment: The DataKeyName is set to ProductID, the user selects a choice from a DDL which loads the formview with details of the selected product. ASP.net newb here, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: What you've posted looks fine, but we can't see how you are binding to the datasource. Have a look at this reference MSDN example and see if you can spot any differences: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227970.aspx Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar problem, then I studied MSDN and it said use UpdateCommand with SqlDataSource, and it worked. 
Here is my code:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:conString %>"
      SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT * FROM [employees] WHERE ([username] = @username)"
      UpdateCommand="UPDATE [employees] SET first_name = @first_name WHERE username = @username">
```